# How to overwrite a table in PostgresSQL using copy_from in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have written a python script that copies the data from CSV to PostgresSQL table using psycopg2 copy_from function.

But I noticed that the data keeps on getting appended rather than getting overwritten in the table.

I need to overwrite the table. Is it possible to achieve by copy_from or copy_expert function in python?

I know I can achieve that by copying the data from CSV to a temporary table and then dropping the original table and rename the temp table, but I want to avoid that approach.

What are other optimum alternatives I can use to overwrite large tables on a daily basis from data in CSV?

Comment: why you dont use a store procedures that first delete all table and then insert?

Comment: Why stored procedures? Can't I just write delete and insert query directly?

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a function which encapsulates copy_from function and has the following piece of code before calling copy_from, in order to truncate the table:

```
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        connection.execute(f"TRUNCATE {table_name};")
```